# Alternative options for ethernet over 75 ohm coax?

Tags: ethernet, adapter

I'm in need of running ethernet between nodes in an older brick, steel & mortar building where 802.11* at any power just simply stinks, and no we can't run CAT5 through the walls.  Primarily this is to connect several media centers to an internet line.

What is wired in ubiquity though is 75 ohm coax F connector'd.

DLink apparently makes a product:  http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=668

Any other (less pricey) suggestions for running data via 75ohm?

Comment: I don't suppose that taping some cat-5 to one end of the coax and heaving at the other end of the coax is a practical strategy?  Forklift upgrades, the cabling way!

Comment: Wish I could.  Building already has cable connectors drilled through the walls already.  It's a leased historical office building so can't make material alterations.

Answer (score 3):

Netgear [has one](http://www.netgear.com/Products/PowerlineNetworking/Coax/MCAB1001.aspx) that's US$199.99 for a pair.

Actiontec has a [couple](http://www.actiontec.com/products/product.php?pid=81) of [models](http://www.actiontec.com/products/product.php?pid=192). Under $150 per pair.

Motorola has [this](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Telco+Broadband+Networks/Modem+And+Gateway+Accessories/HomePNA3-1Adapter_US-EN).

Search for "HPNA Ethernet" and "MoCA Ethernet".

Comment: This would be fantastic with prices a little lower :)  Each node on this is $.  I'm having nightmares about 10base2 crimping...

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use an Ethernet over Powerline system such the [Planet PL501](http://www.linhawstore.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8_143&products_id=1573). I have setup it up for a few place where they can't run Ethernet cables and it seems to work reasonably well.

Comment: I may, I have no idea however if different parts of the building are main'd from different transformers.

Comment: One of the installs is in two neighbouring buildings and it works between them. That's where the built-in encryption helps. Having said that, you may run into issues in your building if you power feeds are from different sources or are filtering out signals on the power lines in your building.